# How to highlight C/C++ header file names with the listings package?

Tags: listings, highlighting, strings

C/C++ header files can be given in two forms: `<foo>` or `"foo"`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myheader.hpp"
```

By default, `listings` does not recognize the first form, and regards the second form as a string. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    language = C++,
    columns = flexible,
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    stringstyle = \color{red!80!black}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <iostream>
#include "myheader.hpp"
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Wrong highlighting]

For differentiation, I set strings in red. As you can see, `iostream` was not recognized at all, and `"myheader.hpp"` was recognized as a string.

How can I highlight header names in a special way? Maybe like this:

[image: Correct highlighting]

Note that both forms of header files are highlighted in a different way than genuine strings.

(In C++, the only valid occurrence of such names is after `#include`, if that helps.)

Comment: Very related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409859/listings-how-to-colorize-strings-between-angle-brackets

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your reply. Now I see that my question is an exact duplicate of that question.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can vote to close as a duplicate yourself as well.  That way, this question will be linked to the other one, making it easier for others to find it.

Comment: @HenriMenke I did that. Thank you!