Formatting C++ code in LaTeX with colors
I'm trying to integrate C++ code into LaTeX text so that I can visually write explanations of the code or write a specific type of problem. It is very important to understand that I am not trying to get the Program code itself via pdf (I know that everything is already automatically written there), I need it in the text
As you can see, I'm trying to adjust the colors and everything seems to be working, as you can see in the . There is one big problem! C++ libraries are written not in ordinary words, but in <...>. I can write <vector> for example, but I can’t make it completely green. It turns out to make only the vector word itself green, but there are no brackets!
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Set the style for displaying code
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morekeywords={namespace, using, include, for, if, else, return, int, float, double, char, void, bool, struct, class, public, private, protected, const, static, virtual, template, typename, switch, case, default, break, continue, do, while, new, delete, try, catch, throw, inline, typedef, sizeof, enum, extern, volatile, register, union, explicit, friend, operator, this, goto, nullptr, auto, constexpr, decltype},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{empty, false, top, push_back, reserve, begin, end, size, clear, insert, erase, find, count, lower_bound, upper_bound, front, back, at, assign, swap, emplace, emplace_back, pop_back, pop_front, push_front, capacity, max_size, shrink_to_fit, data, cbegin, cend, crbegin, crend, resize, full, is_empty, is_full},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[3]{algorithm, array, atomic, bitset, chrono, codecvt, complex, condition_variable, deque, exception, fstream, functional, future, initializer_list, iomanip, ios, iosfwd, iostream, istream, iterator, limits, list, locale, map, memory, mutex, new, numeric, ostream, queue, random, ratio, regex, scoped_allocator, set, sstream, stack, stdexcept, streambuf, string, strstream, system_error, thread, tuple, type_traits, typeindex, typeinfo, unordered_map, unordered_set, utility, valarray,
    vector},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{DarkGreen},
    literate={\#{\textcolor{blue}{\#}}{1}
    }
}

% Define a new environment for inserting code with a gray background
\newtcbox{\inlinecode}[1][gray!20]{
    on line,
    box align=base,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=3pt,
    outer arc=3pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\inlinecode{\lstinline{#1}}}

If you thought that you can write these brackets in morekeywords=[3], then you are very mistaken, then you will not be able to get any green color
Very important point: I understand that there are mathematical symbols in C++ that represent greater than and less than. I don't need to make all these <> brackets green, I only need to make them green when denoting C++ libraries
Full code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % First in the village
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage[left=15mm, top=1cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=10mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Include a file with settings
\input{cpp_style}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

1. Please don't drag the whole of \code{std} into the global namespace with \code{using namespace std;} - that completely eliminates all the benefits of namespacing and makes your code less predictable.

2. Example of function declaration: \code{void generateSequences()} and \code{int computeValue(int a)}.

3. Using a C++ keyword: \code{if (a > b) \{ std::swap(a, b); \}}

4. Some C++ functions to highlight: \code{empty()}, \code{false}, \code{top()}, \code{push_back()}, \code{reserve()}.

5. Include a library: \code{iostream}, \code{<vector>}, \code{algorithm}.

\end{document}


Please provide a FULL minimal working example.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Added full code

I guess your cpp_style content is your first snippet?

Yes you are right!

@Dmitry Please make a compilable example which we can copy&paste without having to puzzle it together

I even specially sent a photo that I write in TEXT, and not in code using begin

What's the point of closing a question if no one answered it? You didn’t even understand him and ran faster...

There is no information anywhere on my problem, how to make green brackets in the text

the link that samcarter gives shows <> brackets colours in a #include <...>  rather than a type, but it's the same thing to listings

Try making green brackets <> in the text without begin (nothing will work)

@Dmitry You can use the same trick in TEXT. It is even easier there as you can directly use \coloranglebracketstrue

You can use the trick from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409953/36296 to colour your angle brackets:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % First in the village
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage[left=15mm, top=1cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=10mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}



% Set the style for displaying code
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morekeywords={namespace, using, include, for, if, else, return, int, float, double, char, void, bool, struct, class, public, private, protected, const, static, virtual, template, typename, switch, case, default, break, continue, do, while, new, delete, try, catch, throw, inline, typedef, sizeof, enum, extern, volatile, register, union, explicit, friend, operator, this, goto, nullptr, auto, constexpr, decltype},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{empty, false, top, push_back, reserve, begin, end, size, clear, insert, erase, find, count, lower_bound, upper_bound, front, back, at, assign, swap, emplace, emplace_back, pop_back, pop_front, push_front, capacity, max_size, shrink_to_fit, data, cbegin, cend, crbegin, crend, resize, full, is_empty, is_full},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[3]{algorithm, array, atomic, bitset, chrono, codecvt, complex, condition_variable, deque, exception, fstream, functional, future, initializer_list, iomanip, ios, iosfwd, iostream, istream, iterator, limits, list, locale, map, memory, mutex, new, numeric, ostream, queue, random, ratio, regex, scoped_allocator, set, sstream, stack, stdexcept, streambuf, string, strstream, system_error, thread, tuple, type_traits, typeindex, typeinfo, unordered_map, unordered_set, utility, valarray,
    vector},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{DarkGreen},
    moredelim=**[s][\coloroncondition]<>
}

\newif\ifcoloranglebrackets
\coloranglebracketsfalse
\newcommand\coloroncondition{\ifcoloranglebrackets\color{DarkGreen}\fi}

% Define a new environment for inserting code with a gray background
\newtcbox{\inlinecode}[1][gray!20]{
    on line,
    box align=base,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=3pt,
    outer arc=3pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\inlinecode{\lstinline{#1}}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

1. Please don't drag the whole of \code{std} into the global namespace with \code{using namespace std;} - that completely eliminates all the benefits of namespacing and makes your code less predictable.

2. Example of function declaration: \code{void generateSequences()} and \code{int computeValue(int a)}.

3. Using a C++ keyword: \code{if (a > b) \{ std::swap(a, b); \}}

4. Some C++ functions to highlight: \code{empty()}, \code{false}, \code{top()}, \code{push_back()}, \code{reserve()}.

5. Include a library: \code{iostream}, {\coloranglebracketstrue\code{<vector>}}, \code{algorithm}.

\end{document}



This is the first time I've seen such a function for a bracket... Where did you find this anglebracketstrue function?

@Dmitry In the question I suggested as duplicate, an action for which you started to throw rude comments at me

Not rude... I don’t understand why they redirect me to begin if I don’t need it

I'd call comments like "You didn’t even understand him and ran faster... " very rude when the linked post very well contained the solution to your problem.
