Bug with colors when trying to paste C++ code into LaTeX
I have already dealt with a similar problem, that I can’t make the colors in the Text work properly! Now I've switched to the code and made other settings so that they don't conflict, but I'm getting a bug that I can't fix... 
File called cpp_style:
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Settings for inserting full code
\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},        
    stringstyle=\color{red},          
    commentstyle=\color{green},      
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=none,                       
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    xleftmargin=5pt,                 
    literate={
        <{{\color{DarkGreen}<}}1
        >{{\color{DarkGreen}>}}1
    }
}

% Set the style for displaying code
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morekeywords={namespace, using, include, for, if, else, return, int, float, double, char, void, bool, struct, class, public, private, protected, const, static, virtual, template, typename, switch, case, default, break, continue, do, while, new, delete, try, catch, throw, inline, typedef, sizeof, enum, extern, volatile, register, union, explicit, friend, operator, this, goto, nullptr, auto, constexpr, decltype},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{empty, false, top, push_back, reserve, begin, end, size, clear, insert, erase, find, count, lower_bound, upper_bound, front, back, at, assign, swap, emplace, emplace_back, pop_back, pop_front, push_front, capacity, max_size, shrink_to_fit, data, cbegin, cend, crbegin, crend, resize, full, add, ans, sort, uint32_t, uint64_t, static, is_empty, is_full},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[3]{algorithm, array, atomic, bitset, chrono, codecvt, complex, condition_variable, deque, exception, fstream, functional, future, initializer_list, iomanip, ios, iosfwd, iostream, istream, iterator, limits, list, locale, map, memory, mutex, new, numeric, ostream, queue, random, ratio, regex, scoped_allocator, set, sstream, stack, stdexcept, streambuf, string, strstream, system_error, thread, tuple, type_traits, typeindex, typeinfo, unordered_map, min, substr, unordered_set, utility, valarray, bits/stdc++.h, climits, 
    vector},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{DarkGreen},
    %literate={\#{\textcolor{blue}{\#}}{1},
    moredelim=**[s][\coloroncondition]<>
}

\newif\ifb
\bfalse
\newcommand\coloroncondition{\ifb\color{DarkGreen}\fi}

% Define a new environment for inserting code with a gray background
\newtcbox{\inlinecode}[1][gray!20]{
    on line,
    box align=base,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=3pt,
    outer arc=3pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\inlinecode{\lstinline{#1}}}

\btrue

Main code:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[outputdir=out]{minted}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Первый на деревне
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage[left=15mm, top=1cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=10mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Include a file with settings
\input{cpp_style}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

1. Please don't drag the whole of \code{std} into the global namespace with \code{using namespace std;} - that completely eliminates all the benefits of namespacing and makes your code less predictable.

2. Example of function declaration: \code{\#void generateSequences()} and \code{int computeValue(int a)}.

3. Using a C++ keyword: \code{if (a > b) \{ std::swap(a, b); \}}

4. Some C++ functions to highlight: \code{empty()}, \code{false}, \code{top()}, \code{push_back()}, \code{reserve()}.

5. Include a library: \code{<bits/stdc++.h>}, {\code{<vector>}}, \code{<algorithm>}.

\lstset{style=codestyle}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=codestyle]
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int cntOcc(const string& s, const string& t) {
    int cnt = 0;
    size_t pos = s.find(t);
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        cnt++;
        pos = s.find(t, pos + 1);
    }
    return cnt;
}

int minLen(const string& s, const string& t, int k) {
    int n = s.size();
    int t_len = t.size();
    if (cntOcc(s, t) < k) return -1;

    int l = 0, r = 0;
    int occ = 0;
    int min_len = INT_MAX;

    while (r < n) {
        if (s.substr(r, t_len) == t) occ++;
        while (occ >= k) {
            min_len = min(min_len, r - l + t_len);
            if (s.substr(l, t_len) == t) occ--;
            l++;
        }
        r++;
    }
    return min_len;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

I don’t understand why some settings conflict with others... Is it possible to somehow make them automatic so that the color for each function and word is immediately defined in begin, like here on the forum when you paste code into C++?

Welcome! What's the bug exactly? Please minimise your example so it includes just enough code for us to compile and reproduce the problem. Or does the bug really go away if you don't load tikz? Please also state the engine you're using and avoid adding arbitrary tags. Overleaf is just your editor and this has nothing to do with expl3.

I have already said that I would like to make LaTeX automatically detect the color of functions and libraries for C++, like here on the forum. But I have a green tank going on and graphicx has nothing to do with it

Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by 'I have a green tank going on'. And, yes, exactly, graphicx has nothing to do with it. So graphicx doesn't belong in your example, which should be minimal. Please edit the code to include just those things essential to the problem. You said there was a bug, but you've not said what that bug is. TeX SE doesn't automatically do syntax highlighting for C++. Here, it automatically does it for LaTeX. If you want LaTeX to do syntax highlighting, you have to tell it so. Are you asking how to do that? If so, please make that clear. Not doing it isn't a bug.

Off-topic: don't number items manually. Use enumerate.

Sorry. I just realised that you might mean a bug in your code. Is that correct? If so, I totally misunderstood. Usually when people talk about bugs on TeX SE, they mean they think there's a bug in somebody else's code. Either way, minimising your example will help people trying to help you.

Hm, for syntax coloring there are better editors available. For Windows look e.g. for Notepad++. You may have to switch syntax highlighting, e.g. between Tex and C++.

BTW: Your definition of \code is problematic, because it reads the argument before \lstinline is active. See section 5.1 "Listings inside argument" of the listings manual for more information.

literate={         <{{\color{DarkGreen}<}}1         >{{\color{DarkGreen}>}}1     } is not a good idea.

Please minimise your example before posting. In particular remove packages which would force users to compile your code with shell-escape if they aren't relevant to your question. Please also don't distribute your code over multiple code fragments. It is a waste of time if we have to puzzle them together again and again for each of your questions.

Instead of manually setting up colours in listings, maybe the predefined colour styles for minted would serve you better? See https://pygments.org/styles/ for an overview.

Maybe I'm asking this question because I don't like the styles in minted and the fact that they can't be customized? If it can be configured, then show at least one documentation where this can be done! I looked 3 times and it’s nowhere to be found

@Dmitry https://pygments.org/docs/styledevelopment/

So what? You will show a specific moment with an example where you can change colors

And I don't have to know Python to change the code style in LaTeX. Python and LaTeX are not the same thing

If you are so unwilling to use minted, why do you load the package?

Do you really not see that I'm asking a question about listings?

And what do you mean I don’t willingly use it? I repeat, I don’t have to know a programming language to change the code style in LaTeX, since there is a normal listings package in which you can change all the code settings in LaTeX itself

I don’t know why, but this is not written anywhere, not even in the documentation of this package. The problem could be solved at random, that is, trial and error. Pay attention to your designation of brackets, you say that they should be the color DarkGreen, and then you do not write anything. I understand that it’s hard to guess, but for some reason listings works like that
To solve the problem, just say that the “space” character will be black and the global settings will return to normal again, that is, add \ {{\color{black}\ }}1 at the end of the settings and everything will work
Full settings
%Settings for inserting full code
\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black}, %2
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},        
    stringstyle=\color{red},          
    commentstyle={\color{gray}},
    texcl=true,  
    morekeywords=[2]{empty, false, top, push_back, reserve, begin, end, size, clear, insert, erase, find, count, lower_bound, upper_bound, front, back, at, assign, swap, emplace, emplace_back, pop_back, pop_front, push_front, capacity, max_size, shrink_to_fit, data, cbegin, cend, crbegin, crend, resize, full, add, ans, sort, uint32_t, uint64_t, static, is_empty, is_full},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{orange},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    framexleftmargin=1.5em,
    frame=none,
    %linewidth={0.75\linewidth}, % code frame width
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    %showspaces=false,
    %showstringspaces=false,
    %showtabs=false,
    basewidth=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    linewidth=315pt,
    breakatwhitespace=true,                 
    literate={
        <{{\color{DarkGreen}<}}1
        >{{\color{DarkGreen}>}}1
        \ {{\color{black}\ }}1
    }
}


well personally I don't know much of C++ and have no idea which colors in the question are supposed to be wrong, but I know a bit about the listings package and  \ {{\color{black}\ }}1 as "solution" to whatever the problem may be looks definitively odd.

This will colour all < and > in the code, not just the angle brackets.

Compile and check that everything works

Just like your question yesterday: use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409953/36296 to colour the libraries
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % First in the village
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage[left=15mm, top=1cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=10mm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% C++ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}



% Set the style for displaying code
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    morekeywords={namespace, using, include, for, if, else, return, int, float, double, char, void, bool, struct, class, public, private, protected, const, static, virtual, template, typename, switch, case, default, break, continue, do, while, new, delete, try, catch, throw, inline, typedef, sizeof, enum, extern, volatile, register, union, explicit, friend, operator, this, goto, nullptr, auto, constexpr, decltype},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[2]{empty, false, top, push_back, reserve, begin, end, size, clear, insert, erase, find, count, lower_bound, upper_bound, front, back, at, assign, swap, emplace, emplace_back, pop_back, pop_front, push_front, capacity, max_size, shrink_to_fit, data, cbegin, cend, crbegin, crend, resize, full, is_empty, is_full},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[3]{algorithm, array, atomic, bitset, chrono, codecvt, complex, condition_variable, deque, exception, fstream, functional, future, initializer_list, iomanip, ios, iosfwd, iostream, istream, iterator, limits, list, locale, map, memory, mutex, new, numeric, ostream, queue, random, ratio, regex, scoped_allocator, set, sstream, stack, stdexcept, streambuf, string, strstream, system_error, thread, tuple, type_traits, typeindex, typeinfo, unordered_map, unordered_set, utility, valarray,
    vector},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{DarkGreen},
    moredelim=**[directive][\coloranglebracketstrue]\#,
    moredelim=**[s][\coloroncondition]<>
}

\lstdefinestyle{codestyle}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},        
    stringstyle=\color{red},          
    commentstyle=\color{green},      
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=none,                       
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    xleftmargin=5pt,   
}

\newif\ifcoloranglebrackets
\coloranglebracketsfalse
\newcommand\coloroncondition{\ifcoloranglebrackets\color{DarkGreen}\fi}

% Define a new environment for inserting code with a gray background
\newtcbox{\inlinecode}[1][gray!20]{
    on line,
    box align=base,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=3pt,
    outer arc=3pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=2pt,
    right=2pt,
    top=2pt,
    bottom=2pt,
}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\inlinecode{\lstinline{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Please don't drag the whole of \code{std} into the global namespace with \code{using namespace std;} - that completely eliminates all the benefits of namespacing and makes your code less predictable.
\item  Example of function declaration: \code{\#void generateSequences()} and \code{int computeValue(int a)}.
\item Using a C++ keyword: \code{if (a > b) \{ std::swap(a, b); \}}
\item Some C++ functions to highlight: \code{empty()}, \code{false}, \code{top()}, \code{push_back()}, \code{reserve()}.
\item Include a library: {\coloranglebracketstrue\code{<bits/stdc++.h>}, {\code{<vector>}}, \code{<algorithm>}}.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=codestyle]
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int cntOcc(const string& s, const string& t) {
    int cnt = 0;
    size_t pos = s.find(t);
    while (pos != string::npos) {
        cnt++;
        pos = s.find(t, pos + 1);
    }
    return cnt;
}

int minLen(const string& s, const string& t, int k) {
    int n = s.size();
    int t_len = t.size();
    if (cntOcc(s, t) < k) return -1;

    int l = 0, r = 0;
    int occ = 0;
    int min_len = INT_MAX;

    while (r < n) {
        if (s.substr(r, t_len) == t) occ++;
        while (occ >= k) {
            min_len = min(min_len, r - l + t_len);
            if (s.substr(l, t_len) == t) occ--;
            l++;
        }
        r++;
    }
    return min_len;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


